# Implementing an N process barrier using semaphores

Tags: operating-system, computer-science, semaphore, systems-programming, barrier

I'm currently training for an OS exam with previous iterations and I came across this:

> Implement a "N Process Barrier", that
> is, making sure that each process out
> of a group of them waits, at some
> point in its respective execution, for
> the other processes to reach their
> given point.
>
> You have the following
> ops available:
>
> `init(sem,value), wait(sem) and signal(sem)`

N is an arbitrary number. I can make it so that it works for a given number of processes, but not for any number.

Any ideas? It's OK to reply with the pseudo-code, this is not an assignment, just personal study.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This is well presented in [The Little Book of Semaphores](http://greenteapress.com/semaphores/).

```
n = the number of threads
count = 0
mutex = Semaphore(1)
barrier = Semaphore(0)


mutex.wait()
count = count + 1
mutex.signal()

if count == n: barrier.signal() # unblock ONE thread

barrier.wait()
barrier.signal() # once we are unblocked, it's our duty to unblock the next thread
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought of something VERY close.

Comment: Would it be better to put the `if count...` in the mutex block to make sure it's only entered once? The way it stands now it looks like you could potentially enter it twice.

Comment: nvm - looked at the little book and it's ok for it to be signaled twice since this barrier is not being reused so it's final state doesn't matter as long as it accomplished it's goal.

Comment: if you would want to reuse it, you would have to aquire your mutex again right after the last barrier.signal() and decrement the count variable. don't forget to unlock the mutex after that.

but why isn't it necessary to hold the mutex while the if performs a check on count?

Comment: to provide an example: let's say, thread 5 aquires the mutex, increments count and releases the mutex. Now the scheduler switches in another thread, which again aquires the mutex, increments count and releases the mutex. count is now 6, and the barrier will never signal it's thread.

Comment: Upvoted for the reference to the Little Book of Semaphores. It's great! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using N semaphores. Not very sure...

```
semaphore barr[N]
semaphore excl=1
int count=0

int i=1
while (i<=N)
   barr[i]=0 #initialization
   i=i+1

# use, each thread (tid)
wait(excl)
count=count+1
if (count==N)
   int j=1
   while (j<=N)
       signal(barr[j])
       j=j+1
   count=0
signal(excl)
wait(barr[tid])
```

Comment: This would encounter an error. It should be `while (i<N)`. Same thing for the next while loop: `while (j<N)`.

Answer (score 0):

Only 2 barrier semaphores, but not sure...

```
semaphore barr[0..1] # two semaphores: barr[0] and barr[1]
semaphore excl=1
int count=0
int whichOne=0 # select semaphore to avoid race conditions

barr[0]=0 #initialization
barr[1]=0

# sample use
int current   #local for each thread
wait(excl)
current=whichOne
count=count+1
if (count==N)
   int j=1
   while (j<=N)
       signal(barr[current])
       j=j+1
   count=0
   whichOne=1-whichOne # swap barrier to avoid race conditions
signal(excl)
wait(barr[current])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should also work, using only one semaphore (at least if the barrier is not required to be reusable)?

```
n = number of threads
barrier = Semaphore(1 - n)

barrier.signal()
barrier.wait()
barrier.signal()
```