# Print output after parallel threads' one loop of execution

Tags: java, multithreading

I am writing a multithread Java program that simulates [game of life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life). There is one thread for each cell computing the next value for cell aliveness value. I solved %95 of the problem threads working correctly and synchronized but I can't figure out how to print out cell matrix after each step. I have the following run method in my threads:

```
public void run(){
  while(true){ //this may also be finite
    calculateNeighbourCount(); //threads count their alive neighbours
    calculateBarrier(); //Threads wait until all threads complete calculation before changing content
    next();//threads make cell's value the next computed value.
    nextBarrier(); //Threads wait until all threads complete next()
    //Here I want to print out cell matrix
  }
}
```

One possible solution I can think of is to allocate memory considering number of iterations.For example if i have mxn cell matrix and k number of iterations I need mxnxk 3d array. Then I store outputs with proper indexes in this array and output after execution.But this solution seems very bad due to the memory  usage. I need a workaround to print the snapshot of the matrix when all cells changed together.

Comment: so are you talking the matrix is shared belong to all threads? and are you trying to show it in a [thread-safe](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html#synctr) manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the java documentation:

> A CyclicBarrier supports an optional Runnable command that is run once
>   per barrier point, after the last thread in the party arrives, but
>   before any threads are released. This barrier action is useful for
>   updating shared-state before any of the parties continue.

You can see an example in the docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html), but generally, one of the constructors accepts a [Runnable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html). You can use that to do your printing after each cycle.

Comment: I am using this custom barrier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331301/implementing-an-n-process-barrier-using-semaphores