# Synchronization Semaphore

Tags: synchronization, semaphore

I have one parent process and three child processes. The parent process has a piece of code which must be executed after all child processes are terminated. I can handle this by wait() method. It suspends the parent process until all child processes are terminated.

However, I have to handle this by using synchronization semaphore.

Is it possible ?

I think that I can set the semaphore to the value 0, and that piece of code is placed after a `sem_wait()` function which decreases the semaphore value. Since its value is equal to 0, the function suspends the parent semaphore. After that, when each child process finishes its job, it calls `sem_signal()` method which increment the value of the semaphore by one. This solution has a problem :

When one of three child processes increment the value of syn semaphore by 1, the parent process can continue to execute its code, since its value is not equal to 0 anymore.

How can I make the parent process wait for all child process by using semaphore ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this can't be done with one semaphore. Barriers are used for this purpose. You can try [implement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331301/implementing-an-n-process-barrier-using-semaphores#6332417) barriers or use semaphores for all specific roles in the program.

Setup your semaphores:

```
subprocesses_run = Semaphore(3) # means that 3 processes can hold this semaphore
sub1_exit = Semaphore(1) # works like normal mutex
sub2_exit = Semaphore(1)
sub3_exit = Semaphore(1)
```

Parent process:

```
sub1_exit.wait()
sub2_exit.wait()
sub3_exit.wait()

# Do your code

subprocesses_run.signal() # signal for all 3 waiting processes
subprocesses_run.signal()
subprocesses_run.signal()
```

First child process:

```
subprocesses_run.wait()

# Some code here

sub1_exit.signal()
```

In this concept all processes should run in loop.