# Waiting for a zero value on a posix semaphore

Tags: c, unix, synchronization, posix, semaphore

With SystemV semaphore APIs I can wait for a zero (or for an increase) of a given semaphore, but I didn't find anything similar with POSIX APIs.

Let me explain the context.

I have a `master` process that forks and execs N other `child` processes. So the total number of processes is `N+1`. Every process (master + children) have an `init()` step that everyone is going to wait upon so that once everyone is done with the `init()` step, the `N+1` processes can run with the rest of the execution.

In SystemV terms I did it like this:

```c
void wait_zero(int sem_id, int sem_index) {
    // ... 
    struct sembuf sops;
    sops.sem_num = sem_index;
    sops.sem_op = 0; // <-- this is what makes the process wait on a zero value
    sops.sem_flg = 0;

    int res = semop(sem_id, &sops, 1);
    // ...
}

void acquire(int sem_id, int sem_index) {
    // ... 
    struct sembuf sops;
    sops.sem_num = sem_index;
    sops.sem_op = -1;
    sops.sem_flg = 0;

    int res = semop(sem_id, &sops, 1);
    // ...
}
```

Now, assuming I have set the value of a `sync_semaphore` to `N+1`, every process can perform in sequence the acquisition and the zero-waiting on the said semaphore:

```c
// ...
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // obtain sync_semaphore id
    init();
    
    acquire(sync_semaphore);   // decrements sync_semaphore
    wait_zero(sync_semaphore); // waits for it to be zero before proceeding

    // rest of the execution...
}
// ...
```

In POSIX I can set the initial value of a semaphore to a non negative value. I can then perform `sem_wait()` (decrements by 1) and `sem_push()` (increments by 1), but I cannot wait for the semaphore to be zero.
I can't seem to find anything similar with POSIX. Is there any way to accomplish the same effect without any form of busy waiting? This problem relates to `waiting for a condition to be true`, so I'm certain that something must exist and I missing something and couldn't find nothing similar to my problem.
My guess is that this exact problem can't be solved using POSIX semaphores alone because of how their APIs work (maybe with some magic using signals or something?).

I also want to add that it's not that big of a deal for me to use SystemV instead, I'm just curious if there's something I'm missing here.

I tried thinking about creating a variable in the shared memory initialized to the value of `N+1` (total number of processes) and then, using a semaphore, every process would decrement its value and suspend their execution with `pause()` only if `value > 0`, otherwise it would signal every paused process to resume the execution.

This solution should work, but it's kinda cumbersome for something that is done so easily with SystemV APIs

Answer (score 1):

> In POSIX [...] I cannot wait for the semaphore to be zero.

Indeed, POSIX semaphores do not support that feature.  They have a considerably simpler and more streamlined API than Sys V semaphores do, with fewer features.

> Is there any way to accomplish the same effect without any form of busy waiting?

Of course.  The combination of a condition variable and a mutex is the Swiss army knife of synchronization tools, and could be used pretty easily to build a barrier.  In this case you would need a shared counter, too.

Alternatively, you could build the barrier with two semaphores and (again) a shared counter, as described in the first answer to [Implementing an N process barrier using semaphores](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6331301/2402272) (not operating-system specific).  That's similar to your idea, but a little cleverer in that it does not require the program to remember the initial height of the barrier.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the name of the problem, I actually thought of doing the thing you linked although I didn't like it because of its "chain reaction" nature. For instance, I wanted to limit the responsibility of the whole thing to be dependent on just one entity (the semaphore was the central piece and the processes sync based on its value). With the barrier approach it seemed like the responsibility was spread. But I get the advantages, you can have much more flexibility with the barrier logic this way. Thanks again